# Google Analytics - Traffic Source - Search engine - (Not Provided)

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics, now here when I go to "Traffic Source Overview" under that it shows Keyword as "(Not provided)" which is almost 40% of my traffic source. Now more than 90% of search engine traffic is from Google and still out of that for more than 40% of keywords are "(Not provided)".

Can anyone explain me what is going wrong here or how can I get that data? Because that comes as 1st option and is biggest keyword in the list. Will that be some crawler or secure google search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google started [encrypting](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html) searches for users who are logged into their Google account while searching last year. As a result the keyword that the visitors search to arrive to your site is not passed in the referring URL. This change **affects all analytics providers**, not just Google Analytics, moving to another program will change nothing.

Google posted a blog on the subject "[Making search more secure: Accessing search query data in Google Analytics](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/making-search-more-secure-accessing.html)"

> When a signed in user visits your site from an organic Google search,
>   all web analytics services, including Google Analytics, will continue
>   to recognize the visit as Google “organic” search, **but will no longer
>   report the query terms** that the user searched on to reach your site.
>   Keep in mind that the change will affect only a minority of your
>   traffic. You will continue to see aggregate query data with no change,
>   including visits from users who aren’t signed in and visits from
>   Google “cpc”.

[Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/google-to-begin-encrypting-searches-outbound-clicks-by-default-97435) has a good rundown, including an interview with Matt Cutts on the subject:-

> In Google’s new system, referrer data will be blocked. This means site
>   owners will begin to lose valuable data that they depend on, to
>   understand how their sites are found through Google. They’ll still be
>   able to tell that someone came from a Google search. They won’t,
>   however, know what that search was.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Google Analytics does not track keywords typed into Google Instant search very well. Here are some resources about it

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-on-instant-search.html
and
http://www.analyticsevangelist.com/google-analytics/how-to-track-google-instant-with-analytics/

Comment: You're correct that instant search tracking isn't great, but this isn't what's causing the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your keyword ranking in search engine. If it found in top 10 then try to concentrate on another keyword. You have said that your main keyword can't helps to increase traffic on website, so first check Google instant search seems your keyword or not. If not then you have to leave that keyword because mostly, all people search those keywords which shows by Google instant.

Comment: The point of the question is that the keyword isn't being displayed. So how do you intend to check it?