# Why is the Google Analytics keyword report showing items that start with "cache:"?

Tags: google-analytics, search-results, cache

When I check Google Analytics, I see some keywords like `cache:2933b974en0J:https://example.com/subservice/well-digging`

[image]

Why is this showing in google analytics?
What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics keyword report is now useless.   Google search used to send the phrase that the user searched in the referrer.   Google Analytics parsed those out of the referrer into a report.   Google stopped sending that keyword data and now Google Analytics shows "(not provided)" in that report instead of useful data.  See [Google Analytics - Traffic Source - Search engine - (Not Provided)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30776/google-analytics-traffic-source-search-engine-not-provided)

When you see a keyword that starts with "cache:" that is from a visitor that viewed a cached copy of your page from the Google search results.

[image]

When they view the cached copy and then click to your site, Google Analytics sees this value in the referrer and erroneously includes it in the keyword report.

There is really no way to fix this.  Google Analytics has been doing that for years and it doesn't cause real problems other than noise in this report.  Since the report doesn't have real keywords in it anymore, you should just be ignoring the report altogether.

To get the keywords for your website, set up Google Search console and look at the "search analytics" reports there.  That is the only reliable source for keyword data these days.   You can even link the search console data to your analytics so that you can see the data in a separate report there.