# How do I track organic keyword conversion rates with Google Analytics G4, Google Tag Manager and Google Search Console?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've tried everything I can think of and googled all over the place but I can't figure out how to connect an organic search term to a conversion event in Analytics G4. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

I'm using Google Tag manager and I've linked Google Search Console to G4.
I have set up an event on the thank-you-page to track conversions.
But I can't seem to match the organic search terms to a conversion. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. There is no way to associate organic search terms with particular sessions and then to conversions.

Through Google Search Console, Google only provides aggregate data about the number of clicks and impressions for your top search terms. Google doesn't provide session level data or conversion level data about organic search terms.

Years ago, the organic search term was available in the referrer from Google search.  Back in the day, it was possible to match organic search terms to conversions.  In the name of user privacy Google stopped sending the search term in the referrer and only started providing the aggregate data through GSC.  See [Google Analytics - Traffic Source - Search engine - (Not Provided)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30776/google-analytics-traffic-source-search-engine-not-provided)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I just have to accept it I guess.

Comment: You and me both.  That data was so useful and I'm still sad that it is gone 10 years later.